# How to create a full-screen background video with some margins?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full screen background video on landing page that covers entire viewport. I'd like to actually contain the video and show some white to the left and right on all screen sizes. I tried changing width and height of container to no luck... I also added some margins but they disappear as the screen gets smaller. Any thoughts?

```css
    .vid {
      position: relative;
      height: 100vh;

 
    }

    .video-container:before {
      content:"";
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
      z-index:1;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      opacity: .5;
      }


    .video-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
 
    }

    .bg-video {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;

     }
```

```html
    <section class="vid p-5">
        <div class="video-container h-100">
            <video class="bg-video" autoplay muted loop>
              <source src="video/caleb-original.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser is not supported
            </video>
          </div>
          <div class="row h-100 text-white">
            <div class="container banner">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 motto text-left">
                 
                  <h1 class="banner-heading  text-left">
                    We Believe<br> <span class="people">People Make<br> The Difference</span>
                    </h1>
                      <a href="#" class="launch-modal" data-modal-id="modal-video">
                                    <span class="hvr-grow u-media-player__icon u-media-player__icon--success">
                                      <span class="fa fa-play u-media-player__icon-inner"></span>
                                   </span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="container">
         <div class="top-footer">
            <h5>Founded 2004</h5>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/theMassPayWay" target="_blank"  ><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/theMassPayWay" target="_blank" ><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfOk5GTwjjbOybKFQotRzmQ?view_as=subscriber" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/themasspayway" target="_blank" ><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/masspay" target="_blank" ><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `width` to your parent `div` and give `margin:0 auto` to that `div`.

Try this:

```
.vid {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: hmmm that worked on larger screen but then as I shrunk screen size video went full width again...

Comment: If you give width 80% and margin:0 auto then it will always show 10% white space both of the side left and right..can you add working fiddle here ? With video

Comment: I'm thinking of have an error or some other css affecting it....It works like it should in the fiddle .https://jsfiddle.net/hendy6/aq9Laaew/257551/

Comment: Might be possible check in developer tool is there is any css that overriding your css